How can I cancel all file downloads at once in Chrome?
How can I cancel all file downloads at once in Chrome? I use Chrome with Windows.
I didn't find the option:


It does not appear that there is an option.  I checked Chromium and Edge, and they don't have an option either.  An extension would have to provide this type of functionality.

@Ramhound got it, thanks!


How can I cancel all file downloads at once in Chrome?

Google Chrome on Windows currently offers no way cancel all file downloads at once.

Canceling all file downloads at once in Chrome is easy. Just click the three-dot menu icon in the top-right corner and select "Downloads" to see a list of your active downloads. Find the "Delete" button and click it. This will instantly cancel all ongoing downloads with one click. This is a convenient way to quickly pause multiple downloads.
